# write formula to an excel column with for loop and if statement

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I intent to use python to write excel formula to a particular column 'M'. But i want to skip/ignore if another column name "Status" contain the word Closed. I'm open to all other method that works.

My codes:

```
for row in range(len(df["Status"])):
        for x in range(len(df["Status"])):
            if str(df["Status"]) == "Closed":
                break   
        
        else:
            dateFmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd mmm yyyy'})
            formula1 = f'=IF(M{row}="Pending", N{row}-D{row}, IF(M{row}="Closed", VALUE(L{row}), IF(M{row}="Select...", "NA")))'
            formula2 = f'=IF(M{row}="Closed", VALUE(N{row}), IF(M{row}="Pending", TODAY()))'
            worksheet.write_formula(f'N{row}', formula2, dateFmt)
            worksheet.write_formula(f'L{row}', formula1)
```

I expect it to be like this:
[expected output with formula applied by python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgzGt.png)

But my codes give me this:
[not the outcome i wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8SlT.png)

**Additional Details**
I wanted to use Python to look through the whole column M "Status" in my Excel Data. If column M contain the word 'Closed', skip that row and do nothing. If contain the word 'Pending', input a formula to another column L and column N.

My code did not skip the row that contain the word Closed, and reset data value to Zero, date to year 1900(see photo) and my heading become FALSE. However, it **work perfectly** for rows that contain the word Pending(see photo).

Comment: I cannot see the connection between your question and your expected output. To me it looks like you have a formula whether the status is closed or not ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ScottC edited with more details:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot verify your excel formulas, however, this is the logic that I would apply to your code.

- Only write the formula to rows which contain the **Pending** status
- Ignore the lines when the status is **Closed**

```py
for row, status in enumerate(df.Status):
    if status == "Pending":
        dateFmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd mmm yyyy'})
        formula1 = f'=IF(M{row}="Pending", N{row}-D{row}, IF(M{row}="Closed", VALUE(L{row}), IF(M{row}="Select...", "NA")))'
        formula2 = f'=IF(M{row}="Closed", VALUE(N{row}), IF(M{row}="Pending", TODAY()))'
        worksheet.write_formula(f'N{row}', formula2, dateFmt)
        worksheet.write_formula(f'L{row}', formula1)
```

[image: ADDED photo for ref: It affect 2 rows before]

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you:), it work some how. The enumerate method did work for all "Pending" rows and ignore the "Closed", that is the result i want. But it affect 2 rows before(see photo). Any idea what went wrong? See photo.

Comment: I'm using xlsxwriter to write formula to Excel. Not sure if this affect how enumerate looping.

Comment: Are you sure this is not an issue with the formulas already in excel sheet? Perhaps replace the formulas in the script with "****" to see exactly which cells are being written to, and which ones are not.

Comment: I added +2 and it working fine now. Not sure why the code works too, i'm new to coding. 

for row, status in enumerate(df.Status, **+2**):

Comment: interesting - at least it works - but looks like you had to put an offset in. I have no idea why that would work - but it is hard to know when I have such a narrow field of view :)